# Mono is 1, Stereo is 2, what is 3?

Tags: adjectives, numbers

Cellphone cameras have moved from a single lens to a dual lens arrangement in recent years and the next iPhone is rumored to have three. There's "Monoscopic" vision, "Stereoscopic" vision, but what's the word for "3-scopic" vision?

Comment: *Stereo* is originally derived from Ancient Greek στερεός (stereós, “solid”). It is not directly related to the number 2, though obvious stereo sound can be reproduced via *two channels, each playing a portion of the original sound in such a way as to create the illusion of locating the sound at a particular position, each offset from the other, thereby more accurately imitating the location of the original sound when the recorded or reproduced sound is heard.*  quoting https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stereo#Noun

Comment: The term "tri-aural" has been used in the past to describe 3-channel sound, though lately it's been co-opted to describe ultrasonic sensors.

Comment: How many people are there with three eyes?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Looks like "Triscopic camera" and "tiraural" are going to be the best answers, although it's interesting to note the greek origin of stereo meaning "solid". Solid might be more apt for devices that can measure things from a 3D perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The words 'triscopic' and 'triscopy' appear in the heading of a scientific paper and in the text of a medical paper but I have not been able to find such words in the OED or Merriam Webster.

> Development of X-ray **triscopic** imaging system towards three-dimensional measurements of dynamical samples

[IOPscience.org](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1748-0221/8/05/C05002)

> Is routine *triple endoscopy* cost-effective in head and neck cancer? ..... 
>   cost-effectiveness of routine **triscopy** in every patient with head and neck cancer.

[Science Direct](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0002961088800369)